# How to send SMS to mobile from SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server

Currently I am working on core banking project and I am stuck at one point i.e sending SMS from SQL Server.

When customer does any kind of transaction like Credit, Debit, he immediately has to receive an SMS.

I have no idea how to send SMS from SQL Server 2008. Please help to do this guys

Comment: I don't think so there is any way u can send an SMS from SQL Server but you can send a mail from your database .http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/08/23/sql-server-2008-configure-database-mail-send-email-from-sql-database/.

Comment: SQL Server is suitable for many things. This is not one of them.

Comment: Presumably you have some kind of webapp that posts these transactions. You need to write something inside of that to generate your SMS messages, ideally. It's kind of scary that you're asking this here instead of it having been brought up and decided in your design process ahead of code being cut.

Answer (score 0):

You could use xp_sendmail with an email to SMS gateway, like you can find zillion on the net.

Comment: xp_sendmail has been deprecated for 7 years now. At the very least recommend [`sp_send_dbmail`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190307.aspx)

Comment: You are right of course. Old habits don't go away easily. It was just to give a general idea though :-)